# Computing $\int \frac{\ln(x)}{(1+x)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve the following integral

$$\int \frac{\ln(x)}{(1+x)^2}dx.$$

I have found a few similar questions on stackexchange but usually involving boundaries, so the answers have involved methods that don't seem applicable when the integral is unbounded.

I have tried using partial integration $\int fg dx = Fg - \int Fg'dx$ with $f=ln(x)$ and $g = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ and the other way around but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partial integration actually works:
$$\int \frac{\log(x)}{(1+x)^2}dx=-\frac{\log(x)}{(1+x)}+\int\frac{1}{x(1+x)}dx$$
and this last one you can easily solve by writing
$$\frac{1}{x(1+x)}=\frac1{x}-\frac{1}{1+x},$$
thus one obtains
$$\int \frac{\log(x)}{(1+x)^2}dx=-\frac{\log(x)}{(1+x)}+\log(x)-\log(1+x)+C$$

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to do the partial fraction thing with $\frac{1}{x(1+x)}$. That certainly made it a lot easier!

Comment: Indeed! Rational functions are easy to deal with, once you train partial fraction decomposition ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to use repeated integration by parts to get
$$ \int\frac{\log x}{(1+x)^2}\,dx = C +\log(x)-\frac{\log x}{1+x}-\log(1+x). $$
Differentiation under the integral sign is another viable alternative to get the same.